# How to install ASF MapReady software in Ubuntu?

Tags: sudo, make, configure

I am trying to install a software named ASF MapReady from [github](https://github.com/asfadmin/ASF_MapReady). But unable to proceed while running the first step `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` as in the description of github. The error I get:

`Configuring ASF Tools
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking for flex... flex
    checking lex output file root... lex.yy
    checking lex library... -lfl
    checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
    checking for bison... bison -y
    checking for fopen in -lc... yes
    checking for main in -lm... yes
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
    checking for cos in -lm... yes
    checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... no
    checking for gsl_blas_dgemm in -lgsl... no
    checking for GSL... no
    checking for gsl_blas_dgemm in -lgsl... (cached) no
    configure: error: library gsl was not found`

How do I install this software in Ubuntu 18.10 ?

Comment: Your error message states that 'library gsl was not found'. Did you read the library requirements listed on the github README? It looks like you need to install `libgsl-dev`

Comment: I installed the gsl now I am getting 'configure: error: library shapelib was not found' .Then I installed shapelib still I get the same error

Comment: That's good. Are you reading the list of required libraries and installing the libraries that you are missing? Did you install shapelib or libshp-dev? It makes a difference.

Comment: I had to install one by one different libraries as mentioned in the Readme. Finally I got to open the gui from the terminal

Comment: It will be better if you write as answer. I will accept it. Also, if you can upvote the question it would look useful for someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are compiling ASF MapReady from source. Their [GitHub README](https://github.com/asfadmin/ASF_MapReady/blob/devel/README.md) says this:

> Prerequisites:
>
> The ASF Tools depend on a number of libraries that you'll need to have
>   installed on your system. In the list below, some of the listed packages
>   will have additional dependencies that your package management system
>   should automatically pull in.
>
> On Debian 9/Ubuntu 16.04, the following packages are necessary:
>
> - gcc
> - g++
> - bison
> - flex
> - libcunit1-dev
> - libexif-dev
> - libfftw3-dev
> - libgdal-dev
> - libgeotiff-dev
> - libglade2-dev
> - libglib2.0-dev
> - libgsl-dev
> - libgtk2.0-dev
> - libjpeg-dev
> - libpng-dev
> - libproj-dev
> - libshp-dev
> - libtiff5-dev
> - libxml2-dev

Which means you need to install all these packages before you can compile MapReady.

And how would you do that? Like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc g++ bison flex libcunit1-dev libexif-dev libfftw3-dev libgdal-dev libgeotiff-dev libglade2-dev libglib2.0-dev libgsl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libproj-dev libshp-dev libtiff5-dev libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message states that the `library gsl was not found`.

One way to determine which library to install is to run the command `apt search gsl` and, looking at the results, try and make an educated guess at which package that you would need to install. The, run the command `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` again to see if the program compiles, or if you are missing additional libraries. Ordinarily, you would need to repeat this process until the compilation is finally successful.

Fortunately, the developer(s) of this project have provided a detailed list in their [README](https://github.com/asfadmin/ASF_MapReady/blob/devel/README.md) of package dependencies required by this tool.

Once you have installed gsl with the command `sudo apt install libgsl-dev`, you will need to work through rest of the dependency list in the README and verify that all of the named packages are indeed present on your system.